# how to add a feature to all wp post at once

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have website with 200 post and each one have +50 pictures without text content and that slow down the loading of my website .. i want to split the loading of picture using a button when the user click on it will be loaded more 10 picture and so on till the end and i don't know how to add the js function to the word-press 
i found some plugin but split to many pagy with `<--next page -->`
but i need some thing like that to keep the user in the some page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lazy Loading" might be able to do what you need, although not exactly what you would like to do with a button and javascript. It is an optimization technique that only loads a picture when it's visible on the area of the browser, and delay loading the rest of the pictures until you scroll down or when they should become visible.

You can configure that when a page loads, only the pictures that are "Above the Fold" (printed on the top half of a browser without scrolling down) should load, and delay loading the rest until a user scrolls down to reveal them.

You can check this document [How to Implement WordPress Lazy Load on Images and Videos](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-lazy-load/).

Check out these lazy load plugins:
https://wpneon.com/best-wordpress-lazy-load-plugins/